# How to retrieve card information such as card number with react-stripe-js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, stripe-payments

I have

```
const stripeResponse = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(client_secret, {
      payment_method: {
        card: elements.getElement('cardNumber'),
        billing_details: {
          address: {
            city: selectedAddress.town,
            country: selectedAddress.country.iso3166Code,
            line1: selectedAddress.line1,
            line2: selectedAddress.line2,
            postal_code: selectedAddress.postalCode,
            state: selectedAddress.region,
          },
          email: 'ppp@mail.com',
          name,
          phone: selectedAddress.phone,
        },
      },
    });
```

With this I confirm card setup and I am using react-stripe-js inside react component:

```
import { CardNumberElement } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
//some component code below
...
<CardNumberElement options={options} />
...
```

It is not possible to get card number from `CardNumberElement` component.

How can I get card number with stripe?

the closest thing I could find was as below, but I need client js preferably react version of it
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You cannot get the card number from Stripe. That is a big part of why you need to use Stripe's libraries, so that card details don't touch your integration.

Full raw card number is never exposed in API responses from Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide

Comment: is it possible to get at least the last 4 digits of a card number?

Comment: yes, when you create a PaymentMethod using Stripe Elements, the PaymentMethod object you get back has last4 field on it

Comment: onFormComplete={cardDetails => {
          console.log('card details', cardDetails);
          setCard(cardDetails);
        }}  here you will get like this in console. card details {"brand": "Visa", "complete": true, "country": "IN", "expiryMonth": 12, "expiryYear": 2039, "last4": "4242", "postalCode": ""}

Answer (score -1):

### If you want to just get the last 4 digits of card number in React-native then

```
onFormComplete={cardDetails => { console.log('card details', cardDetails); setCard(cardDetails); }}
```

here you will get like this in console.

```
card details {"brand": "Visa", "complete": true, "country": "IN", "expiryMonth": 12, "expiryYear": 2039, "last4": "4242", "postalCode": ""
```

### OR

If you want to get all card details then

```
dangerouslyGetFullCardDetails={true}
```

Comment: `dangerouslyGetFullCardDetails` is not available in Stripe.js which is what the question is about so there's no way to get the card number from Stripe.js/Elements. This param exists on the native mobile SDKs. Regardless, you should not access the raw card details for PCI compliance reasons.